# When send sql query with form Access to this resource on the server is denied

Tags: php, mysql, post, access-denied

I'm trying to submit a query to the database via the form. I'm running the query that comes with php on the database. But I'm getting the error in the picture

The query i am trying to send
[image: the query i am trying to send]

The error i got

[image: Error]

But if I send single line it works.
Example:

```
update uretim10dk set mesai_durumu='Mesai dışı' where saat between '00:00' and '08:00';
```

Example2:

```
update uretim10dk set mesai_durumu='Mesai içi' where saat >= '08:00';
```

but not working together.

Example:

```
update uretim10dk set mesai_durumu='Mesai dışı' where saat between '00:00' and '08:00';update uretim10dk set mesai_durumu='Mesai içi' where saat >= '08:00';



  <form action="" method="post">
  <textarea name="sorgularMesai"  id="sorgularMesai" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="gonder" id="gonder" />
</form>




 function GenelMesaiAyarla( $sorgular_mesai_sql ) {
    $yol = $_SESSION[ 'kok_dizin' ] . "DatabaseOperations/ConnectionOperations.php";
    require_once( $yol );
      $connect = new Connection();
      $connect->BaglantiyiAc();
      $connect = new Connection();
      $bolunmus_mesai_sql = explode( ";", $sorgular_mesai_sql );
      for ( $i = 0; $i < count( $bolunmus_mesai_sql ); $i++ ) {
        $connect->BaglantiyiAc();
        $queryMesaiGuncelleResult = $connect->connectionKey->query( $bolunmus_mesai_sql[ $i ] );
        if ( $queryMesaiGuncelleResult ) {
          $connect->BaglantiyiKapat();
          $mesaiGuncellemeDurum = true;
        } else {
          $mesaiGuncellemeDurum = false;
        }
    
        echo $i.":".$bolunmus_mesai_sql[ $i ]."<br>";
      }
    
      return $mesaiGuncellemeDurum;
    }

if ( $_POST ) {

  $sorgular_mesai = $_POST[ "sorgularMesai" ];
  $genel_mesai_durum = "İşlem Başarısız!";
  
    $genel_mesai_durum = GenelMesaiAyarla( $sorgular_mesai );
    if ( $genel_mesai_durum == true ) {
      echo "Mesai güncellendi";
    } else {
      $genel_sonuc = "Mesai Durumu ayarlarken bir sorun oluştuğu için,tüm işlemler durduruldu!";
    }
    }
```

Comment: _“But if I send single line it works.”_ - then I’m guessing that it is probably not your script’s fault, but that some component before that is scanning the parameters for possible “attacks”, and the combination of SQL statements plus semicolons probably makes it think there is some SQL injection attempt going on here, or something like that. Have you first of all checked access & error logs, to see if those have more details?

Comment: Where is the log files in ftp bro?